# Editing the font and style of the text in the instructions box in MIT Scratch project page

Tags: mit-scratch

**The problem:** How do I change the font in the instruction text box in an MIT Scratch project page. For example: make a line of text standout in bold. I believe it maybe done through editing the html code that is behind the box as I found a read only editor button that displays the code for the box. Unlike say a cell in  Ipython you cannot simply surround text with  tags. It seems such a simple problem but I have not found the solution yet.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about using the Scratch website, not programming in Scratch.

Comment: I don't think it can be done... The site doesn't take HTML snippets or similar like markdown.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about using the Scratch website, not programming in Scratch.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, you can't do it.
The only thing you can do is to search for special font-characters and paste them in the Instruction text-box

Answer (score 0):

For a day or two fairly recently this was allowed from a bug, but that bug was fixed and it's now impossible.

Comment: Can you give me the source I would like to check it out. They should ask for suggestions on what users need more frequently or it will stand still.

Comment: [Here](https://scratch.mit.edu/discuss/topic/120312/) is the discussion topic by JamesOuO. It looks like the comment VoltageGames made was deleted, but if you look around (and others') [profile](https://scratch.mit.edu/users/JamesOuO) page, you can clearly see people testing it.. the bug was fixed, though, and now you can't put HTLM in your comments.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to change the HTML code, but that changes would only seen by you, and nobody else. There isn't a way to do it.